# How to handle "Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close" to add event after calling dispose in flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management

I have bloc inside my login page but after I click log out button and login again using wrong password (to see and print the failed response).. I always get `Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close` I have closed my function inside dispose but I still get `Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close`
here is part of my code

```
class Login {
  final _repository = Repository();

  final _loginController = StreamController<List<dynamic>>();
  Stream<List<dynamic>> get loginData => _loginController.stream;

  final _name = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  final _password = BehaviorSubject<String>();

  //Login initialData
  retrieveLoginData(String name, String password) async {
    List<LoginRespon> post = await _repository.addSave(name, password);
    _loginController.sink.add(post); // the error (paused on exception) comes from here
  }

  addSave() {
    _repository.addSave(_name.value, _password.value);
  }

  dispose() {
    _name.close();
    _password.close();
    _loginController.close(); 
  }
}

final bloc = Login();
```

is there something that I should add inside my code to pprevent that error?

Comment: that means that dispose has been already called before you try to access a stream

Comment: is there a way to access stream when dispose has been already called?